# ggplot2 shadings and multiple data points in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have measured the `emission` of two `compounds` `acetone` and `acetaldehyde` nine times across 116 `days`. I made a graph like this:

[image]

The measurements are divided into three `groups`: `a`, `b` and `c`.

I'm trying to plot the average (and standard error) of group `b` and `c` in the graph as well. This symbol would have to be different.

Any ideas?

The data looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(compound = c("Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone"
), days = c(0, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 81, 94, 116, 0, 4, 10, 17, 
24, 66, 81, 94, 116), emission = c(26.13, 59.09, 45, 11.41, 6.71, 
0.07, 0, 0.53, 0.56, 28.47, 46.65, 44.03, 56.68, 29.08, 2.73, 
7.72, 0.38, 0.21), se = c(5.88, 11.04, 11.4, 4.31, 3.54, 0.03, 
0, 0.25, 0.31, 7.44, 8.98, 9.92, 22.79, 13.83, 1.2, 6.38, 0.09, 
0.07), group = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the code for my graph looks like this:

```
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days, y=emission))+
  geom_point(color="darkblue", size=3.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=emission, ymax=emission+se), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(0.05)) +
  labs(color = "", size= "") +
  labs(x = "Incubation time (days)", y = "Production (umol g-1 dw soil h-1)") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(compound), scales = "free_y")
```

---------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------

I can see I did a terrible job trying to explain what I'm trying to do.

The data has a column called `group`. In this column the measurements are divided into `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to plot the average of each of these groups on top of the plot I've showed (where all measurements. There is only one measurement in `a`, so it does not make sense for this group. However for group `b` and `c` I wish to plot the average (and standard error) in the graph as well. These symbols would of course need to be different from what I've already plotted.

Also, I'm trying to change the color of the background behind each of the `groups`, to have different colors similar to this figure I found on google:

[image].

Comment: Can you define how the measurements are divided into three groups? Also variable `daysincubated4` seems to be missing. Great if you could make the question reproducible.

Comment: You want to graph all three measurment(a,b,c) in one plot (overlaying) or different plot? What do you mean by background color?

Comment: Thanks for your correction @Peter. I'm not sure what you mean by reproducible though?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Killbill! Yes everything should be in one plot.

Comment: Reproducible: when someone else copies the data and code from the question into their console the code generates the problem as set out in the question. Have a read of  [MRE] for a really helpful guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited my answer:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(plotrix)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)

#creating group b acetaldehyde mean and standart error
b_mean_ald <- mean(df$emission[df$group == "b" & df$compound == "Acetaldehyde"])
b_se_ald <- std.error(df$emission[df$group == "b" & df$compound == "Acetaldehyde"])

#creating group b acetone mean and standart error
b_mean_acet <- mean(df$emission[df$group == "b" & df$compound == "Acetone"])
b_se_acet <- std.error(df$emission[df$group == "b" & df$compound == "Acetone"])

#creating group c acetaldehyde mean and standart error
c_mean_ald <- mean(df$emission[df$group == "c" & df$compound == "Acetaldehyde"])
c_se_ald <- std.error(df$emission[df$group == "c" & df$compound == "Acetaldehyde"])

#creating group c acetone mean and standart error
c_mean_acet <- mean(df$emission[df$group == "c" & df$compound == "Acetone"])
c_se_acet <- std.error(df$emission[df$group == "c" & df$compound == "Acetone"])


# making a dataframe which contains mean and se of each compounds per groups
mean_df <- data.frame(
  compound = c("Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone"),
  days = c(33, 95, 33, 95),
  emission = c(b_mean_ald, c_mean_ald, b_mean_acet, c_mean_acet),
  se = c(b_se_ald, c_se_ald, b_se_acet, c_se_acet), 
  group = c("b", "c", "b", "c")
)
```

That is the final df(df_fin) looks like:
[image]

Now we apply it in the ggplot:

```
#final plot
df_fin%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days, y=emission))+
  labs(color = "", size= "") +
  labs(x = "Incubation time (days)", y = "Production (umol g-1 dw soil h-1)") +
  facet_wrap(vars(compound), scales = "free_y") +
  
  geom_rect( xmin = 2.2, xmax = 69, ymin = -5, ymax = 85,
             alpha = 0.05, fill="green") +
  geom_rect( xmin = 69, xmax = 125, ymin = -5, ymax = 85,
             alpha = 0.05, fill="yellow")+
  geom_rect( xmin = -10, xmax = 2.2, ymin = -5, ymax = 85,
             alpha = 0.05, fill="purple")+
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = days, y = emission, ymin = emission, ymax = emission + se, color = category, shape = category, group = category),
                  size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), 
                     values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(17, 19))+

  theme_bw()
```

The final plot:

[image]

If you want to include groups in legend also you should do a little tricky:

```
#final plot with groups and measurments legend
df_fin%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days, y=emission))+
  labs(color = "", size= "") +
  labs(x = "Incubation time (days)", y = "Production (umol g-1 dw soil h-1)") +
  facet_wrap(vars(compound), scales = "free_y") +
  geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 2.2, ymin = 85, ymax = 100,
            fill="green",alpha = 0.05)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 2.2, xmax = 69, ymin = 85, ymax = 100,
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 85, ymax = 100,
            fill="purple",alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 2.2, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill="green",alpha = 0.05)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 2.2, xmax = 69, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill="purple",alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -2, xmax = 2.2, ymin = 0, ymax = 85,
              fill="A", alpha = "D"))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 2.2, xmax = 69, ymin = 0, ymax = 85,
             fill = "B", alpha = "E")) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 0, ymax = 85,
              fill="C",alpha = "F"))+
  
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = days, y = emission, ymin = emission, ymax = emission + se, color = category, shape = category, group = category),
                  size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Measurments", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), 
                     values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Groups", labels = c("A", "B","C"), values = c("green", "yellow","purple"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Measurments", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(17, 19))+
  scale_alpha_manual(name = "Groups", labels = c("A", "B", "C"), values = c(0.05,0.05,0.05)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

Plot with groups and measurments legend:
[image]

 In the last plot, because small rectangle of legends with alpha values are not visualized well, we override the legend alpha without affecting main plot alpha, by guides() function in the end of the plot code
So the legends of the groups have more alpha than the main plot.

In this plot, intentionally I set the alpha of the legend groups to 1 and alpha of the plot to 0.05 to show their difference. You can set any alpha to each of them to make them more similar
The plot below shows simingly the similar alpha of the legend and plot:
(by setting plot alpha to 0.05 and legend alpha to 0.2)

[image]

---------
You can also add `theme_bw()` at the end of the last plot to create border (I did not include it in the last plot)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Killbill. I did however explain myself quite poorly in the question, so this is not exactly what I'm seeking. I have update my original question so that it hopefully now is easier to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That looks really good @Killbill! Is it possible to have the triangles same color and size and then have a legend with the triangle and the blue circle? Next to the triangle would say period mean and next to the circle emission.

Comment: @Tiptop, I editted my answer, it has a legend containing groups and measurments symbols.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot @Killbill. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I seem to have some issues getting the legend colors to match the plot colors. I guess it's because the colors are doubled in the plot. I tried to remove ```  geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 2.2, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill="green",alpha = 0.05)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 2.2, xmax = 69, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
            fill="purple",alpha = 0.05) +  geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 2.2, ymin = -20, ymax = 0,
 ``` However I found that the colors were still a bit off.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as how to fix it?

Comment: geom_rect(x=...) without aes draw a rectangle on the plot which does not affect scale of the axis, so we can extend the rectangle to the most top or low area of the plot. I used them to draw  rectangles in the upper and lower portion of the plot. But if you want to have rectangle in the plot panel with legend you shoud put color in the austhetic of  geom_rect(aes(x= ..)). Geom_rect(aes()) and geom_rect() in my plot does jot overlap in  the panel area. So what do you mean by "a bit off". If you can post your plot, it would be easier to be fixed

Comment: All right, it might just be on my screen, but in the plot you printed in your answer the colors in the legend seem a bit brighter than the colors in the actual graph. Anyway increasing alpha parameters in probably an easy fix!

Comment: @Tiptop, now you can see the final plot in my editted answer, with legend alpha differing from plot alpha. Please copy the new final plot code completely.

Comment: Thanks again @Killbill! However are the colors in the graph now brighter than in the legend?

Comment: You can change it according to your preferred alpha

Comment: You can change the alpha of the legends in the guides() function at the end of the code, and alpha of the plot in the scale_alpha_manual(), one line before last line of the code.

Comment: I added a plot in the my answer with relatively same color of legends and plot.